# How to finish a branch in github

Tags: git, branch, git-flow

I've `develop` and another branch with path spec : `remotes/origin/remotes/origin/feature/mobileapp`.

How do I finish this feature ?

```
git checkout remotes/origin/feature/mobileapp   
Switched to branch 'remotes/origin/feature/mobileapp'
```

but,

```
git flow feature finish remotes/origin/feature/mobileapp  
Fatal: Branch 'feature/remotes/origin/feature/mobileapp' does not exist and is required.
```

I even switched to mobile app branch and tried

```
root@ravi:/home/ravi/case/case-mobile-app# git flow feature finish 
The current HEAD is no feature branch.
```

Please suggest a way to finish this mobile app branch.

Comment: `remotes/origin/` isn't part of the branch name, so do a `git checkout feature/mobileapp`

Comment: # git checkout feature/mobileapp
error: pathspec 'feature/mobileappe' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Is the error when I try to checkout just by using feature/mobileapp

Comment: Could you add the output of `git branch -a` to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You should issue:

```
git checkout feature/mobileapp 
git flow feature finish
```